# Python import a variable and set it as file name for another file

Tags: python, import

I have a one.py as:

one.py

```
def file_save():
    f = th1.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    filename = f.name
    return filename
```

I have another file two.py where i need to open  'filename' from 'one.py':

```
from one import file_save
filename=a
with open(a,'w'):
     print('hello')
```

please help me to fix the problem,its not getting filename.Answers will be appreciated!

one.py is an GUI app,when i import on two.py,its opening the GUI instead of opening a file with the obtained filename.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python to get file name and open in another script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185286/python-to-get-file-name-and-open-in-another-script)

Comment: What is the value of `a` in `filename=a`?

Comment: the a is something like :'C:\Python34\abcd.txt

Comment: *"its not getting filename"* - so **what's happening instead**?

Comment: i mean the value provided such as 'abcd.txt' in filename in one.py is not getting acheived in two.py and not writes/opens the 'abcd.txt' with this name!

Comment: That's because you are not calling `file_save`. Just because you import something doesn't mean it's automatically called. You have to call the method `file_save()` to actually get `filename` back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you meant to do in `two.py` was this: `a = file_save()`

In `two.py` you don't have access to the return variable name. Instead just call the method `file_save()`, which gives you the filename.

```
a = file_save()
with open(a, 'w') as f:
    f.write('hello')
```

Try to get in the habit of doing `with open as`

Comment: i got ouput,but its not writing 'hello' into file even after 'f.close()'

Comment: You don't need to do `f.close` if you have `with open as`. Make sure you are providing a complete path to the file, i.e `C:\users\documents\file.txt`, otherwise if it's just `file.txt` it will save that under the folder that your python script is ran from

Comment: how can i avoid running my gui in two.py from the one.py created application?

Comment: Just put the `file_save` method in the same .py module. You can have multiple methods (def methodName) in the same python module

Comment: even then it runs the entire code when specific function is imported!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58895/discussion-between-user2599709-and-user3914506).

Answer (score 0):

In two.py you need to run the method you created, as the variable filename is a local variable only.

on line two of two.py, do:

```
filename = one.file_save()
```